# Enrich 'kubectl top pod' with node information

Tags: performance, kubernetes, monitoring, kubectl

How can you enrich the `kubectl top pod` command with node information?

Answer (score 0):

This function has helped me recently:

```
ktp() { 
  ( 
    echo "$(kubectl top pod $@ | head -1) NODE"; 
    kubectl top pod $@ --no-headers | head -10 \
    | while read LINE
      do
        NODE=$(kubectl -n $(echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}') get pod $(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}') -o=jsonpath='{.spec.nodeName}')
        echo "$LINE $NODE";
     done;
  ) | column -t; 
}
```

or as a long one-liner

```
ktp() {    (      echo "$(kubectl top pod $@ | head -1) NODE";      kubectl top pod $@ --no-headers | head -10     | while read LINE;       do         NODE=$(kubectl -n $(echo $LINE | awk '{print $1}') get pod $(echo $LINE | awk '{print $2}') -o=jsonpath='{.spec.nodeName}');         echo "$LINE $NODE";      done;   ) | column -t;  }
```

Then you need to replace `kubectl top pod` by `ktp` like in the following example:

```
ktp --all-namespaces --sort-by=memory
```

Output:

```
NAMESPACE      NAME                                      CPU(cores)  MEMORY(bytes)  NODE
kube-system    kube-apiserver-master1                    906m        1620Mi         master1
nginx-ingress  nginx-ingress-fvvmx                       16m         1232Mi         node1
nginx-ingress  nginx-ingress-jv5tv                       1m          1032Mi         node2
get-desktop    get-desktop-7768474668-7w8mf              3m          715Mi          node1
kube-system    kube-controller-manager-master1           170m        707Mi          master1
kube-janitor   kube-janitor-78df48c8d7-fj9w4             451m        674Mi          node2
cert-manager   cert-manager-b4d6fd99b-d6gb7              2m          202Mi          node2
kube-system    weave-net-l8zx8                           3m          174Mi          node2
kube-system    etcd-master1                              310m        164Mi          master1
cert-manager   cert-manager-cainjector-74bfccdfdf-c74dt  3m          137Mi          node1
```

Drawbacks:

- auto-completion does not work for `ktp`
- performance is poor with `n+1` API requests. That is, why I have limited the number of answers to 10. With that, the performance is bearable.

Maybe you will find a better solution?